# Kong/Nginx comes has bizarre upstream host

Tags: nginx, kong

Kong/Nginx (I'm not sure which) changes upstream to unexpected IP address. I want it to leave it as localhost. The failing request was made by web browser to localhost:8443/cost-recovery.

Log message:

```
2020/12/15 16:50:09 [error] 88#0: *522 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /login?state=/cost-recovery HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.65.2:8444/login?state=/cost-recovery", host: "localhost:8443"
```

I don't know where it's getting the 192.168.65.2 host, but want it to be localhost.

I'm using pantsel/konga container which uses Kong version 1.2.3. Configuration was done in part via proxy api requests:

Service Request:

```
{"host":"host.docker.internal","created_at":1608009524,"connect_timeout":60000,"id":"647180a3-6f8c-41ae-9f71-c9fc9db40249","protocol":"http","name":"cost-recovery","read_timeout":60000,"port":8447,"path":null,"updated_at":1608009524,"retries":5,"write_timeout":60000,"tags":null}
```

Route Request:

```
{"id":"24100a1d-c679-46b7-93f3-552b055df26b","tags":null,"paths":["\/cost-recovery"],"destinations":null,"protocols":["https"],"created_at":1608009525,"snis":null,"hosts":null,"name":"cost-recovery-route","preserve_host":true,"regex_priority":0,"strip_path":false,"sources":null,"updated_at":1608009525,"https_redirect_status_code":302,"service":{"id":"647180a3-6f8c-41ae-9f71-c9fc9db40249"},"methods":["GET"]}
```

Plugin Request:

```
{"name": "access-validator", "protocols": ["https"], "route": { "id": "24100a1d-c679-46b7-93f3-552b055df26b"}, "config": {"redirect_login": true}}
```